# JSOM increase maximum size of file to upload

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

Using jsom I have created a custom file upload page to upload file to document library. But it is not uploading files with size more than 2mb.

How can we increase the size?

Comment: You can use the REST api which allows you to upload a maximum of 2GB.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2013, the default file size limit set in Central Administration is for uploading single file manually in SharePoint libraries or using server side code. When you try to upload a file more than 1.5 MB , the following error was thrown

The request message is too large.

You can change the configuration if required from central administration
[refer link](https://reshmeeauckloo.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/sharepoint-2013-how-to-increase-the-file-upload-limit-for-csom-from-2-mb-to-20-mb/)

And if you want to work with larger file than 1.5 MB then Rest is only the option.